# Как в одном запросе получить сумму с group by и без него?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Получаю значение value с учетом group_by, как мне в одном запросе получить ещё и значение без group_by , чтобы сложить все значения ?

Вот часть запроса

```
DB::table('reserv as r')
    ->selectRaw('ch.code as name,round(sum(rd.balance),2)  as value')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->get();
```

в итоге хочу получить

```
[
'value'=1,
'value'=2,
'value'=3,
'total'=6
]
```

Comment: так откуда они возьмутся - другие значения?  они в какую-то группу попали

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот такой запрос в код прописать.

```
(SELECT something FROM tablename GROUP BY something ) UNION (SELECT 
SUM(something) AS something FROM tablename)
```